# Interfacing with a second RPi?

Tags: networking, hardware, server

(I am very new with my RPi. It just showed up yesterday! :D As such, sorry if this sounds kind of simple or misinformed)

I have seen many creations online that use 2 or more RPis to make parallel computing platforms.

The first question which needs to be answered is simply:

**Is this even possible?**

Now, my actual question might be a little vague, but I'll try to make it possible to give a single, solid answer:

**What do I need to make two RPis function as a single computer?**

Now, I suppose I could split that up into two different questions:

**What hardware will I need to buy in order to make two RPis function as a single computer?** (connectors, maybe a router if I make them into a sort of server farm? I'm not sure.)

and

**What kind of software am I going to need? Will I need to use a custom OS, or will Raspbian help me with this?**

I have a fair amount of programming and computer experience, but have never done anything like this before. Plus, my Google results have been rather ambiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great to hear you have just recieved your Raspberry Pi!
Instructions to set up the Pi's in the format you desire is documented incredibly well at http://www.southampton.ac.uk/~sjc/raspberrypi/pi_supercomputer_southampton.htm by Professor Simon Cox, the man who originally set up the idea.

I hope this helped you and I cannot wait to see what you make with your new equipment.

Comment: That is perfect! As for my intended projects, I'm going to start with making a Minecraft server. It's simple and easy to set up, and I'm already pretty familiar with it. Eventually I want to turn an array of Pis into a sort of server farm; running a webserver, the aforementioned Minecraftserver, an FTP server, etc. This will be complete with fancy LED displays and stuff. I'm very excited.

Comment: Sounds great, do document your progress on the interwebs for everyone to see!